# Error: org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

I am using Maven first time for my selenium project. Taking a video series help for preparing my test framework.

---

Here is my POM.xml dependency structure:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

---

On running the code following error is showing:

Error: Could not find or load main class com.test.automation.uiAutomation.App

Anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please share full error trace  and ur XML file which ur running ?

Comment: How are you running the code? Have you tried 'mvn clean install' ?

Comment: @AnkurSingh: In the error trace only error is showing: Error: Could not find or load main class com.test.automation.uiAutomation.App. I am sending the xml link shortly.

Comment: @AnkurSingh: Link for POM.XML file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwscTYlxY2vHYTlvaVFRVENLNWM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Mykola: No I am running it as a TestNG class.

Comment: can you share ur code ?

Comment: @AnkurSingh: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BwscTYlxY2vHanEwTDl3Yy1XSUU?usp=sharing Thanks :)

Comment: Which browser ur using ? in chrome ur code is working fine !

Comment: I have tried using both firefox and chrome, issue remains the same: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwscTYlxY2vHSnhkSlFNSjltV3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: shouldn't that be `mvn clean test`

Comment: @Jagjeetsingh - You would need to add a screenshot of your Run Configurations from eclipse. There's something wrong that is happening in your run configuration.